# Get MapKit view border coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

how can I get the MapKit view bounds coordinates for example I need to get the north-east bound coords and the south-west bound coords.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;

minLat = region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0);
maxLat = region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2.0);

minLong = region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
maxLong = region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
```

Northeast coords are (maxLat, maxLong) and southwest coords are (minLat, minLong).

Comment: Should that be `minLat = region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);` and so on for each of them?